# Selenium WebDriver script skip "CTRL + A" step

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I wrote following Selenium WebDriver script for copy all open tabs texts one by one in a single txt file:

```
import pyautogui
import pyperclip
import time

def copy_text_from_tabs(num_tabs, output_file):
    # Delay to ensure you have time to focus on Firefox
    print("Please focus on Firefox within the next 5 seconds...")
    time.sleep(5)

    # Go to the first tab (Ctrl + 1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', '1')

    # Delay to allow time for the page to load
    time.sleep(1)

    # List to store the text from each tab
    tab_texts = []

    # Loop through the number of tabs specified
    for tab_num in range(1, num_tabs + 1):
        # Select all text, copy, and verify
        copied = False
        while not copied:
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
            time.sleep(0.1)  # Give it a short moment for Ctrl + A
            pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
            time.sleep(0.5)  # Short delay to allow clipboard to update
            tab_text = pyperclip.paste()

            # Check if the text was successfully copied and is not empty
            if tab_text.strip():
                copied = True
            else:
                print(f"Retry copying from Tab {tab_num}...")
                time.sleep(1)  # Delay before retrying

        tab_texts.append(f"Tab {tab_num}:\n{tab_text}\n{'/' * 25}\n")  # Add separators between tab texts

        # Switch to the next tab (Ctrl + Tab)
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'tab')
        time.sleep(1)  # Delay to allow time for the page to load

    # Join all the tab texts
    all_text = '\n'.join(tab_texts)

    # Save the text to the output file
    with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        file.write(all_text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num_tabs_to_copy = 100  # Change this number to the desired number of tabs
    output_file_name = "all_tabs_text.txt"

    copy_text_from_tabs(num_tabs_to_copy, output_file_name)

    print("Text copied from tabs and saved to 'all_tabs_text.txt'")
```

but my script sometimes skip "CTRL + A" step and copy nothing in txt file!
where is my script problem?
I even changed sleep time of "CTRL + A" step but script still have problem!
note that this script wrote for firefox Selenium WebDriver

Comment: What environment are you running in? Have you clicked into this area before trying to use ctrl+a?

Comment: @touero I run it on my windows 10 - No I don't click because script must select each tab all texts by CTRL + A and copy all texts, i don't know it need click on blank area in each tab or not!

Comment: There are switch windows method in selenium: `driver.switch_to`, I tried to use ctrl+a select all words in some web, but some of them must click blank area before select them.